# How to find AIC, BIC values for forecasting using `forecast::nnetar` in R?

Tags: r, neural-networks, forecasting, aic, bic

I would like to forecast using a neural network in R. I'm using `forecast::nnetar`.
Can you please suggest how to estimate the AIC/BIC for forecasting using `nnetar`?

Comment: Since NNs usually (and in this case) have no underlying statistical model, I'm afraid that calculating an AIC/BIC does not make sense here. I might be mistaken, tough. (Note that the AIC mentioned in `?forecast::nnetar` refers to selecting the number of nodes via the AIC-optimal AR(p) model.)

Comment: Then how can I select best nn model by varying parameters in nn model? Can you please suggest?

Comment: Fit various models to 90% of your data and use these models to forecast the remaining 10%, i.e., use a *holdout sample*. Choose the model that performs best on the holdout sample ("best" will depend on your error measure(s)). Refit this model on the entire sample. Or consider fitting multiple models and averaging their predictions. However, since your models' forecasts will be rather highly correlated, forecast combination might not be very helpful here.

Comment: Than you Stephan